# JSF 2.0 - How to change the order of popup and ajax execution in <h:commandLink>

Tags: jsf-2

JSF 2.0 - The requirement is to update a selected item from a list of items using popup .

I have used ajax to set the selected item in the jsf managed bean. The ajax is working perfectly but only thing is that my popup is being shown first and then ajax gets called. The problem with this approach is popup gets loaded but the popup is empty and does not show the selected item for update, when I check the managed bean the selected item is correctly set in the managed bean. When I refresh or reload the page and again select a different item for update it shows the previously selected item in the popup, how to make this work correctly?

Please provide the solution for the below specified code snippet:

```
<ui:repeat var="testBean" value="#{testManagedBean.testMap.entrySet().toArray()}">
<tr>
<td><h:commandLink styleClass="topopup2">#{testBean.value.name}
<f:ajax listener="#{testManagedBean.showTestEditPage(testBean.value)}" />
</h:commandLink></td>
</tr>
</ui:repeat>

<div id="toPopup2" style="overflow: scroll; height: 60%; top: 20%;">
<div class="close"></div>
<span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
<br></br> <br></br>
<div id="popup_content popup_content">
<!-- your content start -->
<h:form class="form-horizontal" id="validateUpdate"
onsubmit="return validateUpdate();">
<div class="pe_wrapper">
<div class="row-fluid">
<h2>
<U>Edit Name</U>
</h2>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
Name:
<h:inputText value="#{testManagedBean.testBean.name}" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</h:form>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `toPopup2` initially hidden? how exactly do you display it? i'm sorry, i just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @tt_emrah - Yes it is initially hidden when the page gets loaded, when I click on the command link it shows a popup, the commandLink in the above code has the styleclass="topopup2" which is nothing but the id of <div> tag.